# how to connect to ejabberd server from an other machie in my lan?

Tags: linux, networking, xmpp, ejabberd

i have two linux machines (PC1 and PC2) in my LAN:
in PC1:
I installed the latest ejabberd using:
 
`ejabberd-17.04-linux-x86_64-installer` server and created   `localhost.local domain`.
then i created two users `user1@localhost.local` and `user2@localhost.local`.
i can connect to the users from PC1 and even send messages from user to an other.
what i want  to ask is how can i connect at `user1@localhost.local` from PC2 and send a message to `user2@localhost.local` in PC1.

Comment: you have to assign static ip  in PC1  after that you can access it from other pc also in your LAN .

Comment: @Dhibi.H Have you done it with IP? (I have the same issue. I am running ejabberd server from localhost. I want to switch it to IP. But it is not working.)